# CSS hardware accelerating triggering GPU crash

Tags: css, gpu

On the webapp I'm working on me and my team have some users who is experiencing **browser crashes** when they're using our app. They are then forced to restart the browser. The prolem occurs in all **browsers** on different **OS**'s. We havent found any plugins in the browsers that could affect this issue. We have been tracking our own logs, windows logs etc. without any findings that could relate to the problem. We also watched the **CPU**- and **Hardrive** usage when we succeeded to trigger the problem ourself. But nothing was of the chart. This have made me and my team suspicious that it is **GPU** were having problem with.

We made some research and found out that animation, transition, opacity, transformation in **CSS** can trigger **CSS crashes**. But we don't have the knowledge nor experience to conclude that it's that who is the problem.

We are using **hardware accelerating** **CSS** like:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0) translateZ(0);
```

and some we're also using some **CSS** **rotating keyframe** animations:

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

On some of the users who are experiencing the browser crashes we've implemented a **feature switch**. The **feature switch** removes all **transitions**, **transforms** and **keyframe animations**. They have been telling us that they think the **feature switch** was a improvement. But we can't tell if it's just placebo or if it really did help.

So before we remove a bunch of transtions and transforms from the app I thought it was worth checking out if there are anyone else experiencing the same problems. All thoughts and ideas are welcome.

It's worth mentioning that our webapp is a **one-page-app** using **knockout.js**

Comment: Work computers are rarely made to be performant (unless they have to be). Maybe your use of animations, transforms, etc. is just too much for the computer to handle? Find an old laptop, fire up some CPU/GPU monitoring software, and then browse the most flashy parts of your website.

Comment: We've tried that. But the hardware of the computer dosent seem to be a big parameter in our case. Users with good computers have reported the browser crash.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same kind of trouble which was crashing iOS - Safari browser. I wrote some note that time which is pasted in below -

> 1. Don't use all in transition property, only use which property you want to animate (avoid transition: all 400ms, try transition: color
>      400ms, background 400ms)
> 2. Use keyframe animation as much as you can
> 3. Decrease the size of document
> 4. Reduce request and optimize your images
> 5. Use translate3D, which will force iOS to use 3D acceleration and better memory allocation.
>
> If you are still out of luck, remove all the transition for iOS and
>   animate using JS, i know it's expensive when you can't use library
>   like TweenMax but this is the only solution.
>
> Note: JS animation may affect your animation frame-rate. Using rAF
>   (request frame animation) may enhance a bit.
>
> *** CSS3 animations are very much in-need for website where animation amount is less and it does output ~60 FPS, but JS does vary based on
>   device.

Hope you found it useful. I would suggest you to stick with new feature what you've, just try fix it.

Best of luck.

Comment: I've will most certainly have these things in mind. Thanks for your input :)